# Is that possible calling content script method by context menu item in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to use context menu item to invoke my method written in content script.
Is that possible?

As i have tried, context menu could only doing stuff in backend.
E.g.

```
// A generic onclick callback function.
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
}

// Create one test item for each context type.
var contexts = ["page","selection","link","editable","image","video",
            "audio"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
var context = contexts[i];
var title = "Test '" + context + "' menu item";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                   "onclick": genericOnClick});
console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}
```

This example could not log info on **current page** but on background page.

I have one **content script** to generate something on specified page:

```
var showInfo = function(){ var dialogBoxWrapper = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(dialogBoxWrapper);}
```

and i need invoke this function by context menu.
What shall i do?

Comment: You can invoke methods of content scripts indirectly from background page through context menu using message communication

Comment: Thank you for the reply. can you give me one simple example for this case?

Comment: Check my answer for a sample demonstration

Answer (score 15):

You can refer to following code as a reference, where upon click of a context menu a function in content script is invoked.

## Sample Demonstration

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Content to Context menu",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452777/is-that-possible-calling-content-script-method-by-context-menu-item-in-chrome-ex",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

#### background.js

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
    console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
    console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
    console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));

    //Add all you functional Logic here
    chrome.tabs.query({
        "active": true,
        "currentWindow": true
    }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            "functiontoInvoke": "showInfo"
        });
    });
}

// Create one test item for each context type.
var contexts = ["page", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video",
    "audio"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
    var context = contexts[i];
    var title = "Test '" + context + "' menu item";
    var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": title,
        "contexts": [context],
        "onclick": genericOnClick
    });
    console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
var showInfo = function () {
    console.log("Show Info is invoked");
}
var showAnotherInfo = function () {
    console.log("Show Another Info");
}
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, callback) {
    if (message.functiontoInvoke == "showInfo") {
        showInfo();
    }
    if (message.functiontoInvoke == "showAnotherInfo") {
        showAnotherInfo();
    }
});
```

## References

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Context Menu](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html)
- [Extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use `chrome.tabs.query(...)` instead of just doing `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, ...)`?