# Unable to send message from context menu to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, content-script

I want to send a message to the content script, when the user selects a context menu item. The content script will then, based on the message, format the webpage as required.

I was unable to do so and I have been able to locate the problem to the code responsible for sending the message (in the context menu script) or the one responsible for receiving message (in the content script).

Below, I try to present a simplified version of the code that tries to duplicate the problem:

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MCVE for SO",
    "version": "1",

    "description": "Demonstrate message passing from context menu to content script",

    "author": "Nityesh Agarwal",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus"
    ],  

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["markr.js"]
        }
    ],  

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["backgroundContextMenus.js"]
    }   
}
```

#### backgroundContextMenus.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Testing",
                                "contexts": ["selection"],
                                "id": "testing"});
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
    console.log("testing..");
    console.log("Before sending the bold message");
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {changeParameter: "bold"});
    console.log("After sending the bold message");
});
```

#### markr.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        console.log("Text toggled bold");
    });
```

Upon selecting the context menu item, the `console` shows these messages:

> backgroundContextMenus.js:8 testing..
>   backgroundContextMenus.js:9 Before sending the bold message
>   backgroundContextMenus.js:11 After sending the bold message

So, as you may notice, there is no log saying something like

> Text toggled bold

This means that the code inside the `markr.js` file isn't getting executed. Therefore, I suspect that there must be something wrong with the code responsible for sending message: `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {changeParameter: "bold"});`)

Here's another code snippet which I tried to duplicate but it gave the same problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473739/7082018

---

I am unable to figure out what exactly is wrong with it. It would be of great help if someone could help tell me how I might be able to successfully pass messages between the context menu and the content page.

Comment: chrome.tabs.query is not needed - you have `tab` in onClicked callback so simply send to `tab.id`.

Comment: Note, the web page has its own console and the content script's instance runs there.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes you are right. I have removed the `chrome.tabs.query` and I am now using `tab.id` but this does not mitigate the problem. I am still unable to get the desired log in the console, i.e, "Text toggled bold".

Comment: Sounds like your content script doesn't actually run on the web page. You can check its presence in web page's devtools, Sources panel, Content scripts subpanel.

Comment: Yeah i don't have my content script showing on that panel. Any idea how I might be able to do that? @wOxxOm

Comment: Make sure your declaration of the content script in manifest.json matches the web site URL. Try reloading the extension on chrome://extensions page. Try reloading the web page.

Comment: Just rechecked all of that.. still doesn't work :/ 
Also, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473739/7082018) and I tried to duplicate its code - i created the same exact files with the same exact content - but even that doesn't seem to work. I realise that I might be asking too much of you but could you please look at that? 
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Editing done @wOxxOm Now it is a MCVE, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a cue from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23895822/7082018) I modified my **backgroundContextMenus.js** as follows:

```
function ensureSendMessage(tabId, message, callback){ 
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {ping: true}, function(response){ 
    if(response && response.pong) { // Content script ready
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message, callback);
    } else { // No listener on the other end
      console.log("Injecting script programmatically");
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "markr.js"}, function(){
        if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          throw Error("Unable to inject script into tab " + tabId);
        }
        // OK, now it's injected and ready
        console.log("Sending msg now");
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message, callback);
      });
    }
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Testing",
                                "contexts": ["selection"],
                                "id": "testing"});
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
    ensureSendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"});
});
```

Then I modified the **markr.js** as follows:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.ping){ 
        sendResponse({pong: true}); 
        return; 
    }   
    console.log("Text toggled bold");
});
```

---

Now the console logs are exactly what one may expect:

Console log:

> markr.js:11 Text toggled bold

**Remember that this log is present console log of the webpage's devtools and not the background script's inspect views.**